# What are some other applied advanced probability sub-field relevant to finance?

Tags: probability, applications

What are some other applied advanced probability sub-field relevant to finance?

I have heard Martingale, stochastic process, stochastic calculus, monte-carlo statistics

I've been searching other sub-fields of probability book titles that help to read finance textbook. That is my motivation.

Comment: Quantitative finance, and (a bit of a stretch) actuarial science?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stochastic PDEs, Markov-chain Monte Carlo?

Comment: I've already mention Monte Carlo